# How to type check and access namespace

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have two custom `UITableViewCell` and I wanted to loop through the cells that is currently on my `tableView` when the user taps on the `done` button. I used the`tableView.visibleCells` method to loop through my `tableView`. Here is my code:

```
func doneButtonTapped() {
    // TODO: - Need to collect user's input....

    guard let node = node else {
        return
    }

    var dict: Dictionary<String, Double>

    let calculator = Calculator(module: node.value) // make it a failable initializer, so when user taps done without populating the inputs, it prompts them to

    for cells in tableView.visibleCells {
        if cells is NumericInputTableViewCell {
            print("numeric cell")
            // TODO: - Append to dictionary

            cells. //Error

        } else if cells is BooleanInputTableViewCell {
            print("boolean cell")
            //TODO: - Append to dictionary

        cells. //Error

        }
    } 
}
```

During when I loop through the cells, I check and separate my logic code depending if for-loop found a `NumericInputTableViewCell` or a `BooleanInputTableViewCell` in the if-else statement. when I tried to access the cells's namespace, I got an error and xcode wouldn't auto-complete for me. I should be able to use `cells` in the if statement to access those custom cells. However, I couldn't. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

***UPDATE***

`The error I got is "User of unresolved identifier 'cell'"`

In my custom cells, I got a property called `numericTitleLabel` and when I tried to access that, it gave me that error.

Comment: What is the error? You can't just have `cells.`. Please clarify.

Comment: Just because Xcode does not autocomplete for you it does not mean that your code is invalid.

Comment: thanks, please see update

Comment: Update your question with the actual code causing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`if cell is` checks if cell is some class, if you want to access properties, you should cast your `visibleCell` which is `UITableViewCell`

```
tableView.visibleCells.forEach ({ cell in
    if let numbericCell = cell as? NumericInputTableViewCell {
        print("numeric cell")
        // TODO: - Append to dictionary

        numbericCell..

    } else if let booleanCell = cell as? BooleanInputTableViewCell {
        print("boolean cell")
        //TODO: - Append to dictionary

        booleanCell...
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd that you are looking at `visibleCells` to see what kind items are being represented.

I suggest using the `indexPathsForVisibleRows` and using the returned index paths to query your data source to figure out what is being being displayed.

Comment: I just notice the function `visibleCells` only gives you the cell that are actually visible.